# Ajax jquery searcher

Tags: jquery, search, live, erase

Hello I recently coded this script with a help from some tutorials.
The "problem" is that i want to be able to manually inserting names. As it is now if i type in a name witch does not exsist in db, and click away of the input field, it erases the text i typed in automaticly. I wan't the manually typed in text to be there and the suggestions div must fade out if a user clicks away of the input or uses tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("../autofill_institution.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length > 0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
            $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
            setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the suggestion list when the input looses focus you can do something like this

```
$("idoftheinputfield").on("blur",function(e){
    $('#suggestions').hide()
})
```

It leaves me pondering why your input field is getting cleared when the focus is lost. Anyways if you want to retain the manually typed value you can tweak it a bit like this:

```
$("idoftheinputfield").on("blur",function(e){
    var mycurrentvalue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(mycurrentvalue);
    $('#suggestions').hide()
})
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: saraf->Your first solution did the trick about removing the suggestions. But the second trick did not work :/ :)

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what ecaxtly the bug is yeat, but found out that if i use an older version og Jquery it worked! Wonder wy :/

Comment: hmmm strange... is it giving any error on the second one.. you can see it in action here how does it behave http://jsfiddle.net/p88Sv/

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do with Ajax, PHP and JQuery. Hope this helps or gives you a start.

See live demo and source code here.

http://purpledesign.in/blog/to-create-a-live-search-like-google/

Create a search box, may be an input field like this.

```
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Now we need listen to whatever the user types on the text area. For this we will use the jquery live() and the keyup event. On every keyup we have a jquery function “search” that will run a php script.

Suppose we have the html like this. We have an input field and a list to display the results.

```
 <div class="icon"></div>
 <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
 <ul id="results"></ul>
```

We have a Jquery script that will listen to the keyup event on the input field and if it is not empty it will invoke the search() function. The search() function will run the php script and display the result on the same page using AJAX.

Here is the JQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // Icon Click Focus
        $('div.icon').click(function(){
            $('input#search').focus();
        });

        //Listen for the event
            $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
            // Set Timeout
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

            // Set Search String
            var search_string = $(this).val();

            // Do Search
            if (search_string == '') {
                $("ul#results").fadeOut();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $("ul#results").fadeIn();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
                $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
            };
        });


        // Live Search
        // On Search Submit and Get Results
        function search() {
            var query_value = $('input#search').val();
            $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
            if(query_value !== ''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search_st.php",
                    data: { query: query_value },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("ul#results").html(html);

                    }
                });
            }return false;    
        }



    })

;
```

In the php, shoot a query to the mysql database. The php will return the results that will be put into the html using AJAX. Here the result is put into a html list.

Suppose there is a dummy database containing two tables animals and bird with two similar column names ‘type’ and ‘desc’.

```
//search.php

// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "live";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<li class="result">';
    $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
    $html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
    $html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
    $html .= '</a>';
    $html .= '</li>';
     $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
    $search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = "SELECT *
     FROM animals
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'
     UNION ALL SELECT *
     FROM birf
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'"
     ;
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[] = $results;
        }

        // Check If We Have Results
        if (isset($result_array)) {
            foreach ($result_array as $result) {

                // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
                $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['desc']);
                $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['type']);
            $display_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($result['type']).'&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8';

                // Insert Name
                $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

                // Insert Function
                $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

                // Insert URL
                $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);



                // Output
                echo($output);
            }
        }else{

            // Format No Results Output
            $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
            $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }
```